# MacBook Air number pad keyboard alternative?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Is there any way to set the keyboard on a MacBook Air laptop so that I can toggle between normal keys and a number pad?

Seems a little ridiculous to use the mouse for calculator entry and while the number row is adequate for normal typing, it seems like there should be a way to add this functionality.

(FWIW: late 2012 i7 Intel MBAir, OSX Sierra)

---

per Tom's Comment, as of 12/29/2016 according to their website, "[Karabiner does not work on macOS Sierra at the moment](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)" & just last week there was an [update released for Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele). Here is an old website with some [additional suggestions for how to cross this bridge](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2010060515230735).

Comment: I think it has quite a few years since there was a built-in way to use letter keys for numbers in OS X in an Apple laptop.  I don't know if Karabiner can do it.  Presumably you could make a custom layout with Ukelele.

Comment: @TomGewecke, have you used Ukulele? The reviews I've seen are not so good. Thanks tho for the suggestions, will keep an eye on Karabiner.

Comment: I've made lots of keyboards with ukulele.  Great app, Surprised it would ever get a bad review...

Comment: @TomGewecke that's good to hear - considering your rep, I have more faith in your opinion and experience than random online reviews, thanks!